# Is probability theory just a theory of finite measure in abstract sense? Or is there anything more to it?

Tags: probability-theory

I have had some exposure to measure theoretic probability theory/Brownian motion, and a bit of analysis. There are a lot of theories in probability whose intuition come from real world example but essentially probability theory is a study of random variable whose domain is a sample space, whose measure is 1 (or finite). So in a sense, there's nothing special about probability theory in an abstract sense. If I view it as something in the category of pure mathematics, is it legitimate to say that probability theory is just a subset of analysis dealing with finite measure? Or, is there any subtlety that I'm missing? I'd appreciate any insights.

Comment: What’s the equivalent of the central limit theorem in measure theory?

Comment: I'm not an analyst, but I'm always skeptical of a phrase of the form "X is just Y," because even when true, it's often pretty reductive.

Comment: You could similarly ask something like "is group theory just monoid theory with inverses?" Sure, but the additional assumption(s) lead to a lot of theory that doesn't apply in the more general setting.

Comment: ["At a purely formal level, one could call probability theory the study of measure spaces with total measure one, but that would be like calling number theory the study of strings of digits which terminate."—Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/)

Comment: There is an aspect where probability shines, which is that if you take a family of probability spaces $(X_i,\mathcal E_i,P_i)$, then you can define a *probability* $P$ on $\left(\prod_{i\in I}X_i,\bigotimes_{i\in I}\mathcal E_i\right)$ such that $P[x_{i_1}\in A_{i_1},\cdots, x_{i_n}\in A_{i_n}]=\prod_{j=1}^n P_{i_j}(A_{i_j})$ for all distinct $i_1,\cdots,i_n\in I$. This is essentially the fact that $1$ is the neutral element of the product. Personally I don't know how opportunistic the prominent role of independence is, but it is very relevant for applications nevertheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most important concept that distinguishes probability theory from general measure theory is the notion of independence. Independence of a collection of events $A_i, i \in I$ means that for any finite subcollection $A_{i_1}, \cdots, A_{i_n}$, we have

$$ P(A_{i_1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_n}) = P(A_{i_1}) \cdots P(A_{i_n}) $$

The reason why it is even meaningful to define the notion of independence in probability theory is, of course, $P$ has a total measure of $1$. Otherwise, the product $ P(A_{i_1}) \cdots P(A_{i_n}) $ could quickly blow up without bound.

Comment: If we have two events $A,B$ such that $0<P(A), P(B)<\infty$, then independence implies $P(A), P(B)\leq 1$. That follows from $$P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)\leq P(A),$$ which gives $P(B)\leq 1$. Interchanging the roles yields $P(A)\leq 1$.